# K.clear_session() is not working in Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, backend, google-colaboratory

[image]

Hello.
I am using Colab for ML. Out of sudden, from 1st of August, the model has not been trained with this error message.
This code had never had any problem before 1st of August. I do not know what happened there.
Could you tell me how to solve the problem?
I asked Colab service worker, and they put one single sentence. Ask stackoverflow!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax to do so is :

```
from keras import backend as K 

# Do some code, e.g. train and save model

K.clear_session()
```

another way is :

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```